# Using fgets and using printf only some lines are printed

Tags: c, netbeans, printf

I'm trying to write a function that given some text files it returns some  specific lines. But the problem is some of them are not printed.

I use fgets(var, 1500,(file*)fp) to get every line from a file and then I print it using printf.

The content of the files is like this:

To: Mark

From: Bob

ID: 0

Sun Feb 5 13:21:38 2017

Subject: Football

Text: Next Saturday morning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 void listmails(){


 char To[300];
 char From[300];
 char Date[1500];
 char Subject[300];
 char ID[300];
 char Text[300];
 char llegible[500];
 int countkong = 0;

  FILE *fp;


 while (countkong != -1 ){
 sprintf(llegible, "%d_EDA1_email.txt", countkong); // files name  are of the type 0_EDA1_email.txt, 1_EDA1_email.txt...

 fp = fopen(llegible, "r");
 countkong ++;
 if(fp!=NULL){



       fgets(To, 300, (FILE*)fp); // I don't want to do nothing wit this line, only to jump to the next line of the file

       fgets(From, 300, (FILE*)fp);
       printf("%s\n", From);
       fgets(ID, 300, (FILE*)fp);
       printf("%s\n", ID);
       fgets(Date, 1500, (FILE*)fp);
       fgets(Subject, 300, (FILE*)fp);
       printf("%s\n", Subject);

        }

    }

}


int main()
{

listmails();
return 0;

}
```

[this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCQfZ.png)

Comment: Please include a complete and compilable segment of code, and format for readability.  For starters, you do not need to typecast `fp` in the argument lists.  `fgets(From, 300, fp);` will work just fine as long as `fp` exists after your call to `fopen();`  (which you did not verify).  And lastly, the link to your results should be replaced with a simple text description under you code segment.

Comment: Please include text output in your question as text (code — indent it).  Do not link to images.

Answer (score 2):

If your input file representation is accurate, then you have about 11 or 12 lines, some with visible text, others with only whitespace, likely a new line ( `\n` )

*[fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)*:

> The C library function char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
>   reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string
>   pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the
>   newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever
>   comes first.
>   ...
>   On success, the function returns the same str parameter. If the
>   End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, the
>   contents of str remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned.

As written, your code would appear to read some things okay, just not the things you think it is reading:

```
  fgets(From, 300, (FILE*)fp);  //reads "To: Mark"
   printf("%s\n", From);
   fgets(ID, 300, (FILE*)fp);  //reads "\n"
   printf("%s\n", ID);
```

And so on.

But, from viewing your results, I am not sure what you have included in your code segment is actually what you have compiled.

To improve, experiment with a looping construct to read your file:

```
//to avoid using magic numbers in code, define a line length
#define LINE_LEN (80)

enum {//list all known elements of your file
    to,
    from,
    date,
    subject,
    max_lines
}

char header[max_lines][LINE_LEN];
char body[SOME_LARGER_NUMBER];// hardcoded size not best approach, just for illustration.
int i = 0;
while(fgets(header[i], LINE_LEN, fp))
{
    if(strlen[header[i]) > 1) i++;  //increment lines index only when string has length > 1
}
```

Once you have the header information, start a new loop section to concatenate the body text.